# How to get the menu name of an IAction?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, menu, action

I've defined a menu and an action in plugin.xml.
When

```
IAction.run(IAction action){}
```

is called can I retrieve the name of the menu of this action?

The reason: I've a lot of actions which trigger different wizards. I have to use the menu names as wizard titles. So I thought if I trigger the wizards from the `run()` method I can retrieve the menu names and set the wizard titles. Otherwise I'll have to copy all the menu names from `plugin.properties` to `messages.properties`.

Comment: Have you looked at what `action.getText()` returns?

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks! This should be an accepted answer. The problem was that I used this call but I called `getText()` not of the parameter `action` but of the action instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `getText` method of the `action` parameter:

```java
public void run(IAction action)
{
  String text = action.getText();

  ... more
}
```

Comment: However if the action isn't put inside a menu this works. But I still don't know how to get the name of the parent menu of the action...

Comment: I start thinking about it too. I've tried with `action.getMenuCreator().getMenu(parent)`. But I can't initiate and pass `parent` and even if I could the menu doesn't seem to have a method like `getName()`.